# Xlib (or gtk). C++. Highlight application's window

Tags: c++, gtk, xlib

I've got application for applications sharing (over network). I need to highlight application's window when it is in sharing state. Currently I use `GtkWidget` to create border around the window to show that the window is shared. However there are a lot of problems with this approach (need to hide border when application is minimized, need to resize border when application has changed it's size, etc.).
So the question is there any way to show that the window is shared (highlight it somehow or make it flickering or something like that) using xlib (or gtk) API? I didn't find any useful info in the Internet, so I had to ask it here.
Thanks.

Comment: Search for `XSetWindowBorder` and `XSetWindowBorderWidth`.